# how to loop pyspark dataframe over number of rows in dataframe

Tags: pyspark

my pyspark dataframe is "Values":

```
+------+
|w_vote|
+------+
|   0.1|
|   0.2|
|  0.25|
|   0.3|
|  0.31|
|  0.36|
|  0.41|
|   0.5|
```

I want to loop to each value of a df using pyspark

My code :

```
out = []
for i in values.collect():
    print(i)
```

What i basically want to do is (for (i in 1:nrow(values))

I am trying below code in pyspark but it gives result as below

```
Row(w_vote=0.1)
Row(w_vote=0.2)
Row(w_vote=0.25)
Row(w_vote=0.3)
Row(w_vote=0.31)
Row(w_vote=0.36)
Row(w_vote=0.41)
```

But i want result as 0.1, 0.2, 0.25 etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`collect` returns a `Row` object, which is kind of like a `dict`, except you access elements as attributes, not keys.

Accordingly, you can just do this:

```
result = [row.w_vote for row in values.collect()]
```

Or this:

```
result = [row.asDict()['w_vote'] for row in values.collect()]
```

As a `for`loop:

```
result = []

for row in values.collect():
    result.append(row.w_vote)
```

Comment: Can you please suggest how to incorporate that in for loop, instead of above